# Problems loading Hilva tutorials

Tags: xna-4.0

I'm a newcomer to XNA, and I'm evaluating some libraries. The Hilva Graphics Engine looks interesting, and I'm trying to run their tutorials.  However, all of them give me errors.

For example, if I download the ParallaxMappingSample demo, and try to build it, I get

```
Error   1   Error loading pipeline assembly "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ParallaxMappingSample\Hilva.Content.dll".  ParallaxMappingSample
```

I get similar errors for all of the samples.  Unfortunately, this error isn't very enlightening.  I can see the Hilva.Content.dll in the appropriate directory.  I tried removing and readding the reference from the content project, but I get the same error.

I'm not sure it's relevant, but I'm on Windows 7, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and XNA 4.0.

Is there an easy (or difficult) solution?

EDIT: If you happen to try this, even if you don't have a solution, let me know about it in a comment.  Whether it works for you, or if you get the same problem...either result would be something that might let me know if it's just a problem with the tutorial, or if it's on my end.

Comment: I get the very same error with everyone one of their samples also. I did leave an email on the Hilva Site, and eventually did get reply's but so far none of the reply's I have received can tell me how to get it to compile without erroring, they claim it works for them and they don't don't why it doesn't work for me. I also and running on Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, XNA 4.0 refresh.

Comment: Same problems with me. I think [this clarifies](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114146/Error-loading-pipeline-assembly-compile-error-on) the problem a bit. So I think all their XNA tutorials are just plain broken for XNA 4.0 at least.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about errors in a specific set of tutorials that are known to break on new XNA versions. It would be best brought up with the tutorials' author.

Comment: It wasn't known to *me* that those tutorials would break with new XNA versions, hence the question.